# dictionary to read 3 values from a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to create a simple dictionary which gets 3 values from a csv file. 
my python code can get 2 values easily from the csv file. But I can't get to display a 3th value.

Heres my csv file :

```
  ERRORCODE,EVENTKEY,COUNT 

    109,playback_error,2
    210,live_channels_metadata_request_failed,1
    106,playback_error,19
    180,search_error,5
    2086,vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed,1
    -1001,live_channels_metadata_request_failed,1
    380,playback_error,1
    400,search_error,2
    N/A,crash,218
    3803,playback_error,28
    JX-0002,search_error,104
    385,playback_error,141
    386,playback_error,1
    387,playback_error,29
    0,tbr_error,31
    2001,qp_library_failed_to_start,42
    2002,qp_library_failed_to_start,147
    1512,playback_error,19
    2004,live_channels_metadata_request_failed,2
    2006,qp_library_failed_to_start,1
    2006,live_channels_metadata_request_failed,5
    -1001,search_error,2
    -1003,search_error,8
    BLL-10011,parental_controls_error,42
    1517,playback_error,47
    ,,81
    BL-10013,parental_controls_error,3
    -1005,search_error,3
    BL-10014,parental_controls_error,2
    3320,qp_library_failed_reauthentication,2
    3710,playback_error,168
    -1200,playback_error,2
    -1,playback_error,2
    3301,playback_error,1311
    3304,playback_error,122
    3305,playback_error,1
```

Here's my python dictionary:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
with open('csv_err2.log', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    mydict = dict((rows[0],rows[1]) for rows in reader)
print(mydict)
```

I'm only able to get the following ouput: ERRORCODE, EVENTKEY:

```
{ '3904': 'playback_error', '3808': 'playback_error', '3902': 'qp_library_failed_to_start'..... }
```

but i'm missing the value COUNT.. :(
How can I display my last value COUNT in that dictionary?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: replace `mydict=...` with `mydict = dict((rows[0],[rows[1], rows[2]]) for rows in reader)` not the best way but should work.

Comment: So use `row[2]` in your dictionary too? I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: @user2097159 slices man slices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydict = dict((rows[0],rows[1:]) for rows in reader)
```

might be what you are looking for ... not really sure

Comment: Well played @Joran Beasley